# Prove limit without using operator norm

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

prove $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h)-f(\mathbf{x})-\langle\nabla f(\mathbf{x})h,h\rangle-1/2\langle\nabla^{2}f(\mathbf{x})h,h\rangle}{\|h\|^{2}}=0$$

where function $f:\Bbb{R}^{n} \to \Bbb{R}$ is twice continuously differentiable.